# Run command on remote Unix machine without interactive session

Tags: unix

How can I run a command on a remote Unix machine without starting a interactive session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use ssh:

```
ssh yourusername@yourserver.com "ls -l"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `Subsystem` entry to your `sshd_config` file, if you plan on running a specific command regularly.

```
Subsystem samba-force-election /usr/bin/smbcontrol winbindd force-election
```

Then you can call it with the command '`ssh -s samba-force-election`'.

Most systems have at least one defined:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Which `sftp`, and `scp` call internally when they attempt to run.

Comment: Why is this better than a shell alias?

Comment: You can set it so that no-one has an interactive root shell, but allow them to run commands as root.

Comment: It will automatically work on all computers that need to run the command, and you won't have to update any of them if you need to change the command that is run.